# Android 2.2 - SoundPool sample 0 is not READY

Tags: android, soundpool

I have searched StackOverflow and cannot find a situtation like mine.  I am using four buttons with each button playing a sound file.
I am using SoundPool:
      `SoundPool sound = new SoundPool(4, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);`
I am also using the `OnLoadCompleteListener()` which uses Log to create an I notification in LogCat.
When I launch the program in the emulator I see all four samples complete loading.  During the program three of the sounds will play, however, one will always say:
`WARN/SoundPool(4842):   sample 0 not READY`
Any Ideas.. cause i'm quite flabbergasted.  The sound files are 16-bit pcm wave file playing squarewave tones.
Load Code:

        `sound.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener(){`

```
        @Override
        public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool sound, int sampleId, int status) {
            if(status != 0)
                Log.e("SOUND LOAD"," Sound ID: " + sampleId + " Failed to load.");
            else
                Log.i("SOUND LOAD"," Sound ID: " + sampleId + " loaded.");
        }
    });

    soundID[0] = sound.load(this, R.raw.greennote, 1);
    soundID[1] = sound.load(this, R.raw.rednote, 1);
    soundID[2] = sound.load(this, R.raw.yellownote, 1);
    soundID[3] = sound.load(this, R.raw.bluenote, 1);
```

Play Sound:

```
streamid.setStreamId(myActivity.sound.play(id, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0, 0, 1));
```

Comment: Edit your question to include the code which loads and plays the sounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having the same issues.  From my experiments, it looks like there's something wrong with the ID handling.  SoundPool just doesn't like sound IDs with the number 0.

So I have found a work-around.  Start my sample IDs with 1, not 0.  Hope this works.

Comment: How do you do that? I mean start your sample IDs with 1?

Comment: Hmmm, I was using the SoundPool with a HashMap to keep track of all the different sounds.  With the HashMap, you set the ID (also called a 'key') manually.  Since it sounds like you are not using a HashMap, my comment probably won't make sense.  Good luck anyway!